# PHP - Deliberate loose == check and assigning to if statement

Tags: php

```php
if ($v->getMedical()) {
    $visitorHasMedical = $v->getMedical()->getMedCon() == true; // $visitorHasMedical will be false if "falsey" i.e. empty string or NULL
} else {
    $visitorHasMedical = false;
}
```

Where `getMedical()` is a OneToOne Doctrine relationship that might not exist.

Does this snippet read OK? Firstly, I'm **deliberately** doing a loose == check as this could be NULL or empty string.

Secondly, is assigning $visitorHasMedical to what is essential an if statement OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite so. Except for the trailing comment getting beyond edge. But it can be written in much simpler way anyway.

```
$medical = $v->getMedical();
$visitorHasMedical = ($medical && $medical->getMedCon());
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, I semantically disagree about `$medical && $medical->getMedCon())`. Second I think that piece of code is worth wrapping up into a small method/function. To accomplish this, I'd go for:

```
private function hasMedical(SomeEntity $v): bool {
    if ($v->getMedical() === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return $v->getMedical()->getMedCon()
}
```

However, there is some kind of smell over there that you need to check the null alongside with the bool value. 
Probably you could more cleanly implement it with annotations, mappings, etc.

Comment: Except you got a possible return type error. And btw `getMedical` does not need to be called twice and if anything this should not be private method of who knows, but rather a public method of the visitor entity.